# Control JOIN type between two tables based on parameter value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012-express

This is what I would like to do using SQL Server:

```
declare @isclosed int
set @isclosed=0
declare @jointype varchar(50)

if(isclosed=0)
begin
set @jointype ='left outer join'
end

else
begin
set @jointype ='right outer join'
end


select * from #table1 @jointype  #table2
union
select * from table3
```

How can I use the parameter to do the JOIN?

Comment: You're talking about [dynamic SQL](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/) which should only be used after [you understand the pros and cons](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: So I have to make whole query dynamic for this single changes?

Comment: You'll need a dynamic query but one question, when joining, wouldn't you need to precise upon which column you're joining?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like this ... given your structure (bit value controls what's being executed) you probably don't have to worry about SQL Injection.

```
declare @isclosed int
set @isclosed=0
declare @jointype varchar(50)

if(@isclosed=0)
  begin
    set @jointype ='left outer join'
  end

else
  begin
    set @jointype ='right outer join'
  end

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(4000)
SET @SQL = 

'
SELECT *
FROM
    #table1 
     ' + @jointype  + '
    #table2 ON 
        -- add something here as your JOIN condition

UNION

SELECT * 
FROM table3
'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to make something like this work:

```
declare @isclosed int
set @isclosed=0

-- Since @isclosed can't be equal to 0 and at the same time not equal to 0,
-- only one of the following queries (the ones UNION ALL'd together) will return
-- records.

select * 
from   #table1 
     left outer join  
       #table2 on [whatever]
where (@isclosed=0)
union all 
select *
from   #table1
     right outer join
       #table2 on [whatever]
where (@isclosed <> 0)

union
select * 
from   table3
```

Another option would be to experiment with `FULL OUTER JOIN` and filtering for `NULL`s on the keys of `#table1` or `#table2` depending on the value of `@isclosed`.